# Laravel Notification Facade Queue Response Time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

The Laravel docs explain that when dispatching/sending notifcations, you may want to queue them to speed up application response time.

**https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#queueing-notifications**

This is exactly what I want to do, however I am calling it using the notification facade rather than the notifiable trait. My concern is the former is bypassing the queue, and I need it to notify a group of users at once.

As it says in the docs:

> Alternatively, you may send notifications via the Notification facade.
>   This is useful primarily when you need to send a notification to
>   multiple notifiable entities such as a collection of users.

But when I call my Notification via the facade, it doesn't queue. I know this because when I monitor my network requests and comment out the facade call, my request goes from over 2 seconds (with the notification call) to under .5 seconds (when I comment it out).

Here is the start of my notification class using the queue (`NewAsset`):

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class NewAsset extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
```

Here is the call:

```
$asset = new Asset;
$asset->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$asset->type = "Text";
$asset->content = $content;
$asset->forum_id = 1;
$asset->save();
$users = User::where("id","!=",Auth::user()->id)->get();
Notification::send($users, new NewAsset($asset,Auth::user()));
//if i comment out the notification call above, response time decreases dramatically 
return;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Oh... it seems it is triggering the queue:

```
php artisan queue:listen
[2018-03-31 15:48:22] Processing: App\Notifications\NewAsset
[2018-03-31 15:48:22] Processed:  App\Notifications\NewAsset
[2018-03-31 15:48:23] Processing: App\Notifications\NewAsset
[2018-03-31 15:48:23] Processed:  App\Notifications\NewAsset
[2018-03-31 15:48:24] Processing: App\Notifications\NewAsset
[2018-03-31 15:48:24] Processed:  App\Notifications\NewAsset
[2018-03-31 15:48:25] Processing: App\Notifications\NewAsset
[2018-03-31 15:48:25] Processed:  App\Notifications\NewAsset
```

Why is it so slow then? :(

Comment: Did you include the notifiable trait on your user model?

Comment: @WhyDoesMyCodeWork yes, confirmed it is there.

Comment: @WhyDoesMyCodeWork see command line output edit...

Comment: Which driver are you using for the queue?

Comment: @WhyDoesMyCodeWork database

Comment: how many user do you have?

Comment: @Ben not that many, around 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Notification::send` is slow (> 2 seconds), the chance is, you have thousands of notifiable entities pushing to the database queue, which is slow because thousands of insertion statement executes on database. To improve, you can:

1. Use other queue drivers, such as Amazon SQS, Beanstalkd, Redis etc.. They are optimized for work queue with low latency. They are lightning fast, when compared to database as a work queue.
2. Create another job and let the worker queue all the notifications, for example:

   ```
   php artisan make:job QueueUserNotificationsJob
   ```

   **YourController.php**

   ```
   dispatch(new QueueUserNotificationsJob(Auth::user()->id));
   ```

   **QueueUserNotificationsJob.php**

   ```
   public $authUserId = null;

   public function __construct($authUserId) {

       $this->authUserId = $authUserId;

   }

   public function handle() {

       $users = User::where("id", "!=", $this->authUserId)->get();

       Notification::send($users, new NewAsset($asset, $this->authUserId));

   }
   ```

Comment: I thought the whole point of `implements ShouldQueue` and `Queueable` on the `Notification` was to queue it without having to do this. Isn't running `Notification::send` that way supposed to be async, or no?

Comment: That is what is the difference between making a new job and implementing `ShouldQueue` on the Notification itself?

Comment: The lag is used to push jobs into the queue (creating job), NOT consuming jobs. If database is used as queue driver, it is not optimized as work queue, it just inserts the job one by one which is very slow operations. That's why we will use alternative queue drivers

Comment: So by using one job to queue the various notifications, I avoid the lag... I can't use a different driver at this time. Do the notifications then need `ShouldQueue` and `Queueable` or can I get rid of these? Also is there some documentation or source code you can point me to regarding `creating` versus `consuming` jobs and queues and the associated timing? This is very interesting to me.

Comment: `ShouldQueue` should be implemented if you want to dispatch jobs to various workers. eg, you have 4 workers, and without `ShouldQueue`, the new implementation a worker is used to create and consume jobs, but `ShouldQueue` implemented, a worker is used to create jobs, after that, all workers are used to consume jobs. That's the difference.

Comment: You may find many discussions about (redis vs database), (beanstalkd vs db) on SO etc.. basically database requires disk IO but redis / beanstalkd they are in-memory, so I can say database is slow..