# Batch user notification in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application created using Laravel. There are times that I need to send notification (via Database) to my users.

The problem: Whenever I said notification to all my users (~15k) my app stops working.  Is there any way I can batch this process?

I am using a livewire component to send the notification. When I send a notification to specific users, there's no problem with it. However, when I send the notification to all users, my app freezes.

```
// livewire component
Notification::send($users, new \App\Notifications\SendNotification($this->title, $this->message));
```

This is my SendNotification.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SendNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $title;
    protected $message;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @param $title
     * @param $message
     */
    public function __construct($title, $message)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->title,
            'message' => $this->message,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589359/laravel-notification-facade-queue-response-time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
$when = now()->addSecond();
\Notification::send($users, (new \App\Notifications\SendNotification($this->title, $this->message))->delay($when));
```